# Simple program involving a loop getting stuck for some reason

Tags: c++, string, for-loop

The program is getting stuck when I enter an input string.  I've tested out every other branch in the program so the problem is here.

Note: The infinite loop is intentional and should be broken by the break statement.

```
for (i = 0 ;  i >= 0 ; i++)
{
  text.append("kk");
  if ((text.find("." , j)) < 0 )
  {
     text.erase(text.size() - 2, 2);
     text2.append(text);
     writer << text2 << endl;
     text2.clear();
     j = 0;
     break;
  }
  else
  {
     j = text.find("." , j) + 1; 
     k = j + 1;
     letter = static_cast <int> ( text.at(k) );
     if (( letter < 123 ) && ( letter > 96 ))
     {
       letter = (letter - 32);
       (text.at(k)) = static_cast <char> (letter);
       text.erase(text.size() - 1, 2);
     }
   else 
   {
     text.erase(text.size() - 1, 2); 
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: `std::toupper` will do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please don't write *"for some reason the program is getting stuck"*.  Put your program in a debugger, step through the code, watch the variables, and then you'll **know** *exactly* where and why it got stuck.

Comment: Is ' (text.find("." , j)) < 0 ' ever true? Perhaps you are never meeting this condition and hence never hitting the break statement.

Comment: I'm a person that's been programming for 10 hours total, I don't even know what a debugger is...

Comment: Yes it will break if the conditions are met, but if the conditions are never met it won't break.  Also the continue is useless.

Comment: I should assume so, when the `text.find()` function fails to find anything it should return -1, which is less than 0, and then branch down that path surely?

Comment: Here's what you need to do, google debugging so you know what it is.  Then run your favourite editors debugger in order to fix this problem.  You're not going to get very far programming without learning how to debug so you minds well start now.

Comment: What is a typical input string and what is the expected output?

Comment: Just sentences in general, I'm trying to build a kind of word processor. So "hello. the weather is warm" or just something like that would become "Hello. The weather is warm". I haven't catered for the beginning of the paragraph yet, I'll just do that later.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out already you have an infinite loop. I normally see a string find loop in the following format.

```
int found = 0; 
while ((found = text.find(".", found )) != string::npos) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: the infinite loop is intentional because I don't know how long the string that I'm working with is going to be. It's designed to be broken when the `break` conditions are met.

Comment: @user2779581 I understand, The while loop I posted is the common way to do it. It will search the entire string until their is no more periods left.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'm only really using things that I fully understand right now though. Otherwise I'll just end up using a bunch of things that I don't fully realise the potential of and then I'll just end up being generally poor at this kind of thing. I don't suppose you can see any other potential problem can you?

Comment: @user2779581 No problem, Your current approach has too much branches which can be hard to maintain. infinite loops are great and can sometimes simplify things but this is not a situation for one. Also, its worth the effort to learn common practice and understand why they are common.

Comment: I'm more than aware that it's starting to get unruly! :P I'm going to university in a few days and I'll more than likely learn common practice when I get there, I just wanted to make this before I left as something to do, but nobody seems to know the way around this.

Comment: If you don't want to use a debugger, then I suggest you sprinkle your code with `cout's` or `printf()` to see what the code is doing. This is one common way to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: It's not that I don't want to, I just have no idea how to. I downloaded one and the platform just isn't intuitive so I couldn't get anything from it. Good idea with the couts though, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It's because you never erase the `.` so you never enter your first `if` condition (the one with the break).

Your logic looks like this:

```
Append "kk" to the string
If you don't find a '.'
  exit
Else
  If the second letter after the '.' is lower case
    Change it to upper case
    Delete the last letter in the string
  Else
    Delete the last letter in the string
```

Then you loop again

Assume your string is:  zzz.abcd
your iterations will be:

```
zzz.aBcdk
zzz.aBcdkk
zzz.aBcdkkk
```

etc..

this is the line doing the most of the damage:

`j = text.find("." , j) + 1;`

here, if you don't find the '.', you're setting j to 0 (-1 + 1) so on your next iteration, you're doing exactly the same search again.

Comment: I think you're incorrect if you don't mind me saying. The `j = text.find("." , j) + 1 ;` will make j be a character ahead of the full stop, so it begins searching ahead of it on the next iteration. The k is then 1 character ahead of that, so it's the second character after the full stop. And the `erase` function then deletes the last 2 characters as I understand it, unless I messed up on that part. The reason the k's need to be there at all is because I end up referencing something out of the string's scope if it's not there.

Comment: I've added to my answer to make it clearer.. But I stand by the original. If you were to add a write of the string on every iteration, it would be exactly as I've said.

Comment: but this wouldn't really matter given that if nothing is found it goes straight to the exit surely? So if no period is found it doesn't get to the stage where it can then reset the loop by itself?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Nevermind, my answer is wrong. I wasn't aware that std::npos is a constant set to -1.

The line:
`if ((text.find("." , j)) < 0 )`

will never be true and so the break is never executed.

`std::string.find()` returns `std::npos`, not a value less than 0, if the text isn't found.

See: [std::string.find()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find)

Comment: although you're correct, he should be using std::npos, it actually shouldn't matter anyway, as std::npos is a constant defined as -1

Comment: Yeah I was going to say that I've tried it earlier and it gives -1 when nothing is found. I wish somebody had the answer arghhhhh!!

Comment: I've just used cout in the call for when there's no periods in the sentence and tested it with a string containing no periods, and none of the `cout's` were called. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: I think you code is entirely too complicated. Hint: use the function called std::string.find_first_not_of() after locating a ".".

Answer (score 0):

I know you want to stick with your code, however, it *really* is pretty bad and I'd hate for you to learn bad habits.

Sometimes, even most times, we as developers have to be able to learn from code examples. I know you don't want to use any code constructs that you don't understand. However, in university and on the job you will have to learn from code you don't understand. It is a good way to improve your skill and knowledge.

I've written some code that solves your problem. It may not be the best solution. It's tested and works. Please look over this code and ask if you don't understand anything. Hopefully this will be of value to you.

```
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

void ToUpper( std::string& text, int position );

void ToUpper( std::string& text, int position )
{
    char c;

    c = text.at(position);
    text.at(position) = std::toupper(c);

    return;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string text = "this is. a very simple. example. ok.";

    int found = 0;

    //Handle first character of sentence
    if ((found = text.find_first_not_of(" ", 0)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        ToUpper( text, found );     
    }

    while ((found = text.find(".", found )) != std::string::npos)
    {
        found = text.find_first_not_of(" .", found);
        if( found != std::string::npos )
        {
            ToUpper( text, found );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, firstly I'd just like to say that I really appreciate the sentiment. I don't plan on just ignoring other examples  when it comes  to learning new things, but on this occasion this was just an exercise of the tools that I'd already been taught. I wanted to learn their capabilities and see how they could be utilised to create some cool stuff. I'm certain that there are probably better methods for nearly every aspect of my code, but that wasn't what this exercise was about for me. I just wanted to set myself a challenge with the tools that I had, so I appreciate the effort that you went to

Comment: but I just can't use it I'm afraid :/ Although if you're still willing to help with the problem, I've discovered the problem to be in the call for the program to break. For some reason the if root just isn't followed when a period isn't found. I haven't figured out why yet, I'll probably just work on it some more tomorrow and then if I can't make it, I'll just come back to the whole thing when I've learnt more. Again, thanks so much for your input, I appreciate it.

Comment: Understood. StevieG's answer is correct. He points out what is wrong with the code.

Comment: I don't know if I'm seeing it wrong, but I don't think that answer is right. `j = text.find("." , j) + 1 ; ` is only executed if something is found. If no periods are found in the remaining string then `if ((text.find("." , j)) < 0 )` should take the code down this branch and then exit out of the loop. I can see why the search would start over again if nothing was found, but if nothing is found then it should exit out before it has a chance to change the value of j to 0 shouldn't it?

Comment: And you should probably upvote the answers that you've found useful as this is what helps stackoverflow work.

Comment: How though? `if ((text.find("." , j)) < 0 )` will run before the code that actually sets the value for j, so how would that interfere with the program? And if a period is found then this will set a value for j and then the loop will continue again and if nothing is found, the value for j won't be changed from -1 to zero because the code that does that only happens if something is found. So how is StevieG's answer correct? I don't mind if I'm wrong, I just don't see a flaw in the reasoning that I just gave.